# Getting "Cannot get/" when using a node image with docker and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, visual-studio-code

After a lot of tries I finally managed to get docker on my computer. So I have an app1 directory with the following files:

Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM node:latest
EXPOSE 8080

WORKDIR /app

COPY package-lock.json  .
COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "app1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Then a src directory with server.js:

```js
'use strict';


// load package
const express = require('express');


const PORT = 8080;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';
const app = express();
 
 
app.get('/greeting', (req,res) => {
        
         res.send('hello ');
   });

 app.use('/', express.static('pages'));

   
app.listen(PORT, HOST);

console.log('up and running');
```

From the app1 directory I run:
 `docker build -t raff/node .` The image gets built with no issues. So I try to run docker with `sudo docker run --rm -p 3000:8080 -v /Users/me/Desktop/app1/src:/app/src -it raff/node`

So I get message that node is up and running and as soon as I open localhost:3000 I get the error message.

Could someone point it out what's wrong?

Edit: Included the absolute path that was omitted before.

Comment: Does `localhost:3000/greeting` return hello? It seems like you're not copying your src directory?

Comment: Did you mean to use `./Desktop/app1/src:/app/src`? You need to supply an absolute path when you bind mount.

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze , if I add "/greeting? it does return hello. ```Desktop/app1/src:/app/src```doesn't this line copy my src directory?

@super I do have the absolute path. I apologize as I deleted my absolute path just for privacy. I will add the questions.

Comment: Normally you copy your src directory in your Dockerfile. If get on greeting is working it seems like your static files are not available